# How can I use Tobit David on my Laptop?

Tags: windows, email, mobile-devices

experts and pros! I'd like to install [Tobit David 10](http://www.tobit.com/login/showTopicPerson.asp?NewsID=%7B92D9DF53-AD68-4A9F-BC0E-64C3CF7A9314%7D) on my Laptop to use it from home. I can't find any documentation that can help me configuring the David Server -the programm needs to run on a server for a company.
(David is an email provider, for people who don't know it. Actually, I don't really think that people who don't know it can help me.)
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Edit: I already purchased and installed the mobile licences.

Comment: Couple of things - 1. Please provide a link to the product/homepage of Tobit David.  2.  Please provide a short, 3-4 word description of what Tobit David does.  3.  I do not understand why you want to install a server on your home laptop - are you demoing the software/ practicing your configuration skills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the mobile licences, you just need to activate the replication tool. So you'll have to enter your email server, the username and the password on the "mobile machine", after having configure them in the David Administration Tools.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got the answer: Just had to buy and install David Mobile licences for as many laptop as I needed. Very easy to add to the David Admin Tool. Then by installing on the laptop, just select a mobile installation and activate the replication.